# Can record to be replaced with class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a code that it was use the record to define a member .But I have another project in lower version of .net core , it seems can not use record . How can I change it with class?

origin :

```
public record BucketObject(string name, string urn);
```

can be changed with :

```
    public class BucketObject
    {
        public BucketObject(string _name, string _urn)
        {
            _name = name;
            _urn = urn;
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string urn { get; set; }

    };
```

Comment: Generally, yes. But records have additional behavior that must be explicitly implemented in a class. You can read about that in the docs by Microsoft.

Comment: If you're trying to answer your own question, please post the answer as an answer rather than including it as part of the question. If that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify the question. Explain why the code you've provided doesn't work, including any error messages you may be getting.

Comment: ^^ It may be worthwhile to look at what the record is lowered to: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAIBOBTAxge02HQGF0AKKOABnQDsBDAW2wBp0raBXTOgSgDcQA==

Comment: ^^ _"Generally, yes."_ - I mean: that's what we did before we _had_ records, right? It's just not a simple "drop-in" replacement.

Comment: I will remember this point ! Because I think record and class provide the similiar usage , I can not debug any problem this time .But the project just came out of the different result ,I can not make sure where the problem is it .  I conclude some problems and one of these is "record" , and  I just want mke sure that can be change with class . I will think a better way to explain my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the easiest way would be to add [`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) to your project file and add a [IsExternalInit](https://blog.ndepend.com/using-c9-record-and-init-property-in-your-net-framework-4-x-net-standard-and-net-core-projects/) class.

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal static class IsExternalInit
    {
    }
}
```

If that is not an option the corresponding class would be

```
public class BucketObject : IEquatable<BucketObject>
{
    public BucketObject(string name, string urn)
    {
        Name = name;
        Urn = urn;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Urn { get; }

    public bool Equals(BucketObject other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Name == other.Name && Urn == other.Urn;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((BucketObject)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (Urn != null ? Urn.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BucketObject left, BucketObject right) => Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(BucketObject left, BucketObject right) => !Equals(left, right);
};
```

You might note that most of the code is in the equality comparison methods, these are one of the things the records get you for free. You might also note that the object is immutable, so you do not have to worry about the object changing, or the difference between class/struct.

You will also be missing out on the `myBucket with {Name  = "newName"}` syntax, and that is just unavoidable as far as I know.

You might also just consider upgrading your projects. Life tend to be easier if you keep all the projects at the same version. And if you are already on .net core, updating should be fairly painless.